# Why is the DNS Server not updating with dynamic updates from the DHCP server?

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, windows-server-2016

I'm using Dock to create Windows containers that are visible to the LAN via a transparent network.

The container get's it's IP from our (Windows) DHCP server. 
Everything works fine except that the DNS Server that serves our network does not update after the container got it's DHCP lease.

I've already altered the dynamic update settings to unsecure and secure and also changed the DHCP servers behaviour that it must update DNS entries dynamically every time.

If I recreate this error on a new test machine (Windows Server 2016 SE) and let my docker container use the private network that the server is in, the servers DNS server is updated with the containers hostname

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most often when I see this kind of DHCP-not-updating DNS behavior, it is because the credentials that DHCP uses to do the updates have a problem.

To access the credentials screen - Open up DHCP, right click IPv4 protocol, select the "Advanced Tab", and then the "Credentials" button.

[image]

You should also make sure that the "Dynamically update DNS A and Ptr ..." option is checked on the DNS tab.

[image]

Comment: I had enabled the dynamic updates only for my IPv4 segment, but not for IPv4 itself on the production server. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad to have been a help!